# Background music ducked when Unity3D game is launched

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, unity-game-engine, avaudioplayer

I'm developing a casual game for iOS with the Unity3D engine.

Whenever my game is launched, the background music being played on the device (e.g.: Spotify, iTunes, etc.) is ducked. This is undesired because my game does not have any fancy sound effects, I' like to allow my players to keep listening to their music in the 'normal' volume.

For testing purposes I created an empty project in Unity3D, ensuring the `Override iPad Music` setting is unchecked in the iOS Build Settings. This is enough to reproduce the audio ducking issue.

INFO:

- Unity 5.4.x (also occurs with Unity 5.3.x)
- Xcode 8
- iOS 9 and iOS 10

Does anyone know how disable Unity3D's default audio ducking?

Comment: See discussion here: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/background-music-ducked-when-game-is-launched.434008/#post-2809083

Answer (score 0):

Add an Audio mixer to the output of your audio source. On the Audio mixer in the project tab, click the drop down then click on master. Finally increase the attenuation volume to a level your feel satisfied with. Then you are good to go.